# Websocket not emitting in react and nest.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, nestjs

My goal is to send some data from client (React.js) to server (Nest.js) and make some complex computations on server side. Computations take some time, so I need to send info about progress of computations from server to client. That's why I use websocket instead of REST API.

The problem is, when I try to send some data from server to client during computation process, only first message is received (logged) by client. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but despite of the fact that I place `client.emit()` in loop, so message should be received multiple times, I get only first message.

If you think that my problem (send info about progress from server to client in loop) can be resolved in different way (maybe without WebSocket), your replay will also be appreciated.

Here's my client app code:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');    

socket.emit('correlate', {
   formData: data
}
 }, (res) => {
     // some side effects            
});


// Listen for progress
socket.on('correlate', (d) => {
   console.log(d); // Here only first message in logged
});
```

And server code:

```
for(const relationRow of relationSheet) {
   // complex computations

   client.emit('correlate', 70 * (i / relationSheet.length / 100));
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `@SubscribeMessage('correlate')` decorated method inside your `@WebSocketGateway()` class?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yes I have

Comment: Can you show the server related code?